# WCF service await error?

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, xamarin

trying to troubleshoot my wcf connection when it is throwing this error,
im not really sure what it is telling me as i have never worked with this kind of stuff before

```
    ERROR System error. 
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)
                ERROR System error. 
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke (object,intptr)
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>:end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)
  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>:end_invoke_object__this___object[]&_IAsyncResult (object[]&,System.IAsyncResult)
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.EndProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters, IAsyncResult result) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:460 
  at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.EndProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters, IAsyncResult result) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientRuntimeChannel.cs:460 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+ChannelBase`1[TChannel,T].EndInvoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, IAsyncResult result) [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:404 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1+ChannelBase`1[TChannel,T].EndInvoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, IAsyncResult result) [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:404 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosityClient+CommunityGenerosityClientChannel.EndGetActivitys (IAsyncResult result) [0x00008] in \CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\Service References\CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference\Reference.cs:914 
  at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosityClient+CommunityGenerosityClientChannel.EndGetActivitys (IAsyncResult result) [0x00008] in \CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\Service References\CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference\Reference.cs:914 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosityClient.CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosity.EndGetActivitys (IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in \CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\Service References\CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference\Reference.cs:571 
  at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosityClient.CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference.CommunityGenerosity.EndGetActivitys (IAsyncResult result) [0x00001] in \CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\Service References\CommunityGenerosiryServiceReference\Reference.cs:571 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:552 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:552 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2512/d3008455/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372 
05-31 13:16:42.025 I/mono-stdout( 5037):   at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryService+<GetActivitiesAsync>d__10.MoveNext () [0x00079] in CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerousity\CommunityGenerosiryService.cs:138 
  at CommunityGenerousity.CommunityGenerosiryService+<GetActivitiesAsync>d__10.MoveNext () [0x00079]
```

this is the code that is throwing the error:

```
 var items= await Task.Factory.FromAsync<ObservableCollection<activityWCF>>(service.BeginGetActivitys, service.EndGetActivitys, null, TaskCreationOptions.None);
```

Comment: First check for the InnerException being populated